# Getting weird error that tells me that it try to pop from empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

guys can anyone explain me why my sort function doesn't work? It use to work but feels like I delete some variable when I was cleaning my code and I have no clue what to do now. It tells me that my list is empty and nothing can be popped from it but when I try to print I can see all the values from it. Here is my code:
'''Sorting in ascending order'''

```
def sortFunction(filename):
    am=[]
    pm=[]
    
    for x in filename:
        if x[-2:] == "AM":
            am.append(x)
        else:
            pm.append(x)
    else:
        am.sort()
        am.append(am.pop(0))
        pm.sort()

    my_list = am + pm
    sortedList = []
    for z in my_list:
        z = z.replace(':', ' ')
        sortedList.append(tuple(z.split()))
    print(sortedList)
```

And main function:

```
with open("D:\\test.txt", "r") as file:
    target = file.readline()
    for last_line in file:
        pass
    
#step 2 and step 4  
time_list = create_time_list("D:\\test.txt")

#step 5    
max = sorted(time_list)[-1] 
print(max)

#step 6
sortFunction(time_list)
```

This is the output from the filename variable before for loop:

```
[('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'), ('1', '34', 'AM'), ('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'), ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), ('4', '10', 'PM')]
```

Comment: " It tells me that my list is empty " - please always include the real, complete error traceback in your question. Also, `am.append(am.pop(0))` seems a bit of a strange idea. Do you have a reason for this and do you really mean it?

Comment: no, just first what came in my mind, do python for 2 weeks, not very experienced, still have to learn a lot

Answer (score 1):

In the start of loop the `am` list might be empty so pop might not work.

So just add `elif` instead of `else` and try, see below code:

```
def sortFunction(filename):
    am=[]
    pm=[]
    
    for x in filename:
        if x[-2:] == "AM":
            am.append(x)
        else:
            pm.append(x)
    if am:
        am.sort()
        am.append(am.pop(0))
        pm.sort()

    my_list = am + pm
    sortedList = []
    for z in my_list:
        z = z.replace(':', ' ')
        sortedList.append(tuple(z.split()))
    print(sortedList)
```

By the way `am.append(am.pop(0))` what is meaning of this code?
You are adding first element to last after sorting? Why?

Comment: it doesn't work, elif:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
This is the way how I have been sorting the list of tuples, and it worked before, as I said I had different variable that respond for it and after cleaning the code I lost track of it

Comment: @DenisGojinetchi it is `elif am:` not just `elif:` Please check the above code

Comment: same problem sir 
    elif am:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @DenisGojinetchi sorry it is separate if statement instead of else just make it `if am:` check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

`filename` is a list of tuples, which means `x[-2]` is the last two items in the tuple. Check if the tuple contains `'AM'` instead

```
for x in filename:
    if 'AM' in x:
        am.append(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I used your method and at the end of I sorted one more time before adding in to the final list and it worked.